# Hoe to fix "Networking DNS Proxy -- Permission Denied"

Tags: ios, swift, nednsproxyprovider

I am sorry to public this problem, but I really can not resolve it. I only use NetowrkExtension-DNS Proxy in my app. I finish my app and its functions is normal according to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81103 . But when i publish it by Testflight, there are some thing wrong. When I open proxy after installing my app by TestFlight, I don not see the alert of VPN Authorization and get error -- permission denied. I want to know why and how to resolve it. I am looking forward to your reply, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/dns_proxy_provider):

`DNS proxy providers are only supported on supervised iOS devices.`

That means you can't publish the app trough TestFlight, the only way is to push the app on a [Supervised device](https://simplemdm.com/2016/05/31/what-is-ios-supervised-mode-how-do-i-activate-supervision/), one of the ways is to use an MDM solution (like SimpleMDM)